# Shared storage between C# console application and ASP.NET WebForms application

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, console

There are some `C#` console applications that started by **Windows scheduler**.
How can I gather work progress from any of them (using internal data available only in concrete console application)?
In other words, I want to show some data from running console application on my asp.net webforms website.
 How can i do this?

Comment: Have the console application write values to database. Make the asp.net webform access the same database.

Comment: I f u have same database for both the application then u can easily do things..

Comment: Nope! There is no common database at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Host a http server inside the console app that the website can communicate with. I already kind of do this using self host signal r inside a tray application and it works a treat.

https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/wiki/Self-host

Answer (score 1):

I would preferred old good [.NET Remouting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwdt6w2k%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for this (check out [simple example for it](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10045/NET-Remoting-Sample)). But you can use WCF with NetNamedPipesBinding or NetTcpBinding binding.

Comment: Thanks, but .Net Remoting and WCF is not a good solution for me because i'd like to use received data just on frontend of my asp.net webforms website.